# Querying one table that references another table's PK, is the other tables index used?

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing

For example:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    login_id VARCHAR(20) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    login_password CHAR(60) NOT NULL,
    first_name VARCHAR(20),
    last_name VARCHAR(20),
    email varchar(100),
    last_login_at TIMESTAMP DEFAULT NOW() NOT NULL,
    join_at TIMESTAMP DEFAULT NOW() NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE todos (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    user_id INTEGER REFERENCES USERS(id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    title VARCHAR(500),
    contents VARCHAR(1000),
    done BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE NOT NULL,
    create_at TIMESTAMP DEFAULT NOW() NOT NULL,
    modified_at TIMESTAMP DEFAULT NOW() NOT NULL
);
```

```
SELECT * FROM todos WHERE user_id = 1;
```

If I execute that query, is Postgres going to use the index on `users(id)`? (Data is enough to use index.)

Comment: Where did you create an index on column user_id? It's not in the DDL above

Comment: I don't know Postgresql, but the answer could have been 'Yes' (using another dbms.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I execute that query, is Postgres going to use the index on `users(id)`?

**No.** The table `users` is not even involved in the query you show.

The index on the table `users` cannot help in any way to locate rows in the table `todos`. The FK reference only kicks in when *inserting* / *updating* values in `todos(user_id)` - or *deleting* / *updating* values in `users(id)`.

Create an index on `todos(user_id)` to support your query. Would be a good design decision anyway to support the FK.

Comment: Thank you very much! Even my English is bad you understand my question :)